# Is it possible to wirelessly transmit 1920x1080 32-bit color 30fps video through VGA from laptop to HDTV?

Tags: video, wireless, video-standards, specifications

Is it electrically possible to transmit a 1920x1080 32-bit color image at 30 frames per seconds just being powered off of a laptop's USB2 port?

I am looking for technical information regarding power requirements of VGA at different resolutions, refresh rates, and color depth to see if I could explain to a co-worker whether it is or isn't possible using theoretical math and known benchmarks. (Boss wants to find a wireless VGA transmitter that doesn't require external power source other than USB if it must + driverless/softwareless.)

Comment: I'm confused as to whether you want wireless or not.

Comment: Does it have to be VGA? The only HD transmitters I know of are HDMI or SDI.

Answer (score 1):

On a side note, I believe the power is required for the analog to digital converter in wireless transmissions, and not the signal itself, since there is +5V DC power running through one of the pins. So you might actually have better luck searching for USB powered signal converters, because once the signal is digital, you're home free.

Something like this:

http://www.atlona.com/Atlona-VGA-to-HDMI-Scaler-Converter-USB-Powered.html

Once it's digital, you could use something like this if the little bit of latency isn't a big deal:

http://www.amazon.ca/Nyrius-Transmitter-Streaming-Satellite-NPCS549/dp/B009E6R89C

Answer (score 0):

Without the power requirement it is certainly doable, however I'm not sure it is going to be easily doable with only a USB port to go on since VGA is analog.  If you were to expand to digital options, then WiDi is an option